# What is wrong with my binary search implementation?

Tags: c, binary-search

```
#include <stdio.h>
int bsearch(int a[], int n, int lo, int hi) {
    int mid;
    mid = (hi + lo) / 2;
    if(a[mid] == n)
        return 1;
    else if(a[mid] > n)
        bsearch(a, n, lo, mid);
    else
        bsearch(a, n, mid, hi);
    return 0;
} 

int main(void) {
    int n, a[7] = {2, 4, 5, 67, 70, 80, 81};
    int hi = 6, lo = 0, j;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    j = bsearch(a, n, lo, hi);
    if(j)
        printf("Found");
    else
        printf("Not Found"); 
    return 0;
 }
```

> input : 5 output: Not Found

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this result?

Comment: Are you aware that there is a binary search (with the same name) in stdlib.h? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/bsearch/

Comment: In your bsearch method, would you want to put "return bsearch(a,n..)" in your else-ifs?

Comment: should be `return bsearch(a,n,lo,mid);`, other ditto. and No conditions specified if it is not found.

Comment: As @SaviourSelf indicates, your recursive calls are not returning their result, causing 0 to be returned. This is a mistake that is unlikely to help others so I've voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix several big issues to make it work (see details in following code comments).

Change your binary search function to the following:

```
int bsearch(int a[], int n, int lo, int hi)
{
    // add base case
    if (high < low)  
        return 0; // not found 

    int mid;
    mid=(hi+lo)/2;
    if(a[mid]==n)
        return 1;
    else if(a[mid]>n)
        return bsearch(a,n,lo,mid-1); // add return
    else
        return bsearch(a,n,mid+1,hi); // add return
}
```

---

**P.S.:**  And based on your usage in the `main()` body, you actually only need to return `0/1` to indicate contains the value or not. I will suggest you to use `bool` return type to make it more clear.

Comment: Nothing wrong with his returning 1 if (based on his usage in main) he's only trying to identify if the value was found... but yes, returning the place it was found at is far more useful _IF_ an invalid value is returned to indicate nothing was found. To that end, you perhaps should change the final `return 0;` to `return -1;` (which would break the logic in the OP's main function).

Comment: @mah Added `return 1` back to make it consistent. Thanks.

Comment: `return` does not make it recursive. It is, in fact, recursive as it is. It is simply doing nothing with the values returned in the recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

Add "return" to the recursive calls, e.g.:

```
    return bsearch(a,n,lo,mid);
```

Otherwise, when you return 1 in bsearch, it does not get returned all the way to main.

That will make it work for 5. You have other bugs, so try with many values and use an IDE and/or printf to see what's happening. Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `return 0;` statement in your `bsearch` function is always executed because you are simply discarding the values returned by the recursive calls. In a recursive function, you must first decide the base case. Here in your `bsearch`, the base case should be

```
low <= hi
```

This is the first condition which must be true to start the search for the sought value. If this condition is not fulfilled, then you must return `false`, i.e., `0`.

Next, a value returning function call is an expression, i.e., it evaluates to a value. When you simply call the function and do nothing with the result, you will always fall down to the last return statement in your function. Here I list some points in comments alongside the statements in your `bsearch` function.

```
int bsearch(int a[], int n, int lo, int hi) {
    // first check for the base condition here
    // if(hi < low) return 0;

    int mid;

    // can cause integer overflow. should be
    // mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2; 

    mid = (hi + lo) / 2; 
    if(a[mid] == n)
        return 1;
    else if(a[mid] > n)

        // you are doing nothing with the value returned
        // think of the function call as an expression
        // return the value of the expression
        // should be
        // return besearch(a, n, lo, hi);

        bsearch(a, n, lo, mid); 
    else
        // same follows here
        // should be
        // return bsearch(a, n, mid, hi);

        bsearch(a, n, mid, hi); 

    // finally you will always return 0 because this statement is always executed
    // all cases have been taken care of.
    // no return statement needed here
    return 0; 
}
```